# Calling a standard library function in signal handler

Tags: c, unix, gcc, signals

Why is calling a standard library function inside a signal handler discouraged?

Comment: By discouraged, I meant its undefined behavior.

Comment: But, then also when I use functions like printf(), the code just runs fine...

Comment: Anecdote: I worked on a project that used an Access database.  We had a signal handler that called printf(), but instead of writing to stdout, it would write to the .mdb file, hosing the database beyond repair.  Needless to say, this was inconvenient.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is explained in the [GNU LibC documentation](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Nonreentrancy.html#Nonreentrancy).

> If you call a function in the handler, make sure it is reentrant with respect to signals, or else make sure that the signal cannot interrupt a call to a related function.

And just in case, here's the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_(subroutine)) on reentrant functions.

> A computer program or routine is described as reentrant if it can be safely called again before its previous invocation has been completed (i.e it can be safely executed concurrently).

Answer (score 1):

Its not only re-entrancy issues, depending on the signal being services you also want to avoid inadvertent calls to malloc() (i.e. asprintf()) and other variadic expansion (i.e. printf()).

Answer (score 1):

It is all running fine and stuff, until you run into some mysterious bugs which are totally untraceable :)

`man 7 signal` will give you a list of system calls which are safe to call from a signal handler. It is described in POSIX as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because the library function may not be reentrant.